# How can I get the number of elements in an unsigned char* array?

Tags: c

I have a function that takes in pointers to different arrays which can look like this:

```
    unsigned char *arr[] = {0x34, 0x10, 0x3f, 0x00, 0x00 }
```

I want to know how many elements (bytes) are in each array my function is getting. For example, I need a way to find that this array has 5 bytes. I pass this into a function to print the values of the array. Sizeof(arr) doesn't give me the right results.

Comment: Are you sure that's not supposed to be `unsigned char arr[]`?  Or do you really have pointers like that?

Comment: `sizeof(arr)` **should** give a good result. It's just that you need to declare it using `unsigned char[]` and not `unsigned char *[]`. (And yes, we're operating on **arrays** and **not pointers,** so you won't be able to get a correct result from within a function.)

Comment: @alk Did I write anything else?

Comment: I really do have pointers, so sizeof(arr) is not working well. That's alright, I will try another way.

Comment: you want sizeof(arr)/sizeof(unsigned char*)

Comment: The reason sizeof(arr) doesn't work is that you are probably storing 4 byte pointers and sizeof returns number of bytes.  So the number of elements (5) and the number of bytes used by the array (probably 20 or 40 if using 64bit) are not the same value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is C. and in C this does not exist. You have to somewhere remember /store the number of elements.

Answer (score 4):

Unless you're using a convention like "the array is null-terminated" (like C strings nominally are) you can't determine the size of the array at run-time. All you have at that point is a pointer.

Comment: You can absolutely determine the size of an array at runtime - `sizeof` works on VLAs, for example.  If you pass a *pointer* to an array and try to get the size of the original array, then yes, you're out of luck.

Comment: Yes that's what I was trying to do, I guess it won't be possible.

Comment: People use VLAs? :) Anyway, the way I understand it (and maybe I don't understand it sufficiently), the ability to determine the size is limited to the declaring scope.

Answer (score 0):

```
sizeof(arr)/sizeof(unsigned char*)
```

you can macro-ize this fairly easily as

```
#define ARRAY_LENGTH(_array_)    (sizeof(_array_) / sizeof(_array_[0])
```

BTW, this will only work if you use it in the same scope as the array.  This will not work if you pass the array to a function (and the array degrades into a pointer).  If you pass the array to a function, you'll need to pass the number elements, and possibly the size of each element.